# What do you call a power splitter without a cable?

Tags: electrical, terminology

...No, this is not a setup for a joke.

In Israel we have gadgets like this one:

[image]

It's basically like a power strip, except it doesn't have a cable. You plug it into a lone power socket and now you have 2. It also comes in varieties where it gives you 3 or 4 power outlets.

**Is there a name for this device in English?**

Comment: VTC - This question has nothing to do with DIY home improvement or repair.

Comment: I would call it a 'double adapter'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

'Receptacle multiplier' works on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's called an [outlet tap.](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=outlet%20tap&rlz=1C1GTPM_enIL582IL582&oq=outlet%20tap&aqs=chrome..69i57.367j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)